# Trying to adjust size of shapes in VBA script but cannot get to size precisely

Tags: vba, formatting, resize, shapes

I am finding adjusting the size of shapes in Excel incredibly frustrating. For some reason, when I resize the height, the width adjusts to some random number, and vice versa. I do not have aspect ratio locked, and have *Don't move or size with cells* ticked on. The shapes are circles and I am trying to format them to have equal height and width (12 x 12)

Thinking this was due to some bug in the *Format Shape* controls, I wrote a very simple script to loop over all the shapes in my sheet and correct their properties, but the same problem persists.

```vb
Sub FixButFormat()
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        sh.Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 12
        Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 12
        Selection.Placement = xlMove
        Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your code work as intended? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: No need to select anything, do not use `ShapeRange` property. Use the shape dimensions, properties...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub FixButFormat()
 Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        With sh
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .height = 12
            .width = 12
            .placement = xlMove
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        End With
    Next sh
End Sub
```

But, if the shapes are circles, is it a possibility to not be circles, anymore? I mean having the same dimension on both axes. Otherwise, it is enough to modify only one dimension, keeping `LockAspectRatio = msoTrue`...

Comment: @Munki Fisht: Did you find some time to test the above code? Didn't it work as you need?

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru - Thanks for the response, but the code unfortunately does not work The dims are still changing to some random value around the 12 pt specified in most cases. For example, the first time I ran it changes from 11.4 to 12.15, Then another instance the width might change to 12.3, and the height will also change when the width does. I thought this may be because there was some grid in Excel that was forcing specific dims base on position, so I shifted the shape to Left, Top = 0, 0 and then repositioned back once the scaling had been done, but this also does not work.

Comment: @Munki Fisht: Can you share the workbook you use? On my installation is works exactly as it should. If something confidential in your workbook, please build a dummy one and try sharing it on a transfer site. [Here](https://easyupload.io/) it is a free one, easy to be used. When a tested code does not return what you need, it is at least polite, but in your interest to send some feedback telling what does not behave as you need...